# How to countif date in a specific column

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

[image]

how to countifs date in a specific column and to differentiate between start date and end date count.

Comment: Please elaborate - what do you want returned? The number of days between the start and end date? Or just a count of all the rows where the end date is populated?

Comment: Example: 
1.By putting the formula, it will count how much 2/2/16 at the end date column.
2.It show the quantity of 2/2/16 from end date at the below table referring the date at the table.
3.The count will not include the start date.
Hope you can help.

Comment: you have two questions with the same pictures, with almost no descriptions. Please rework them and make sure: you show only parts of the sheets really interesting (currently it's very difficult to see the details) and clearly describe what you want to achieve, mentioning also what should be the result (even if it's on the screenshot, we can't know whether it's the one you need). Also please include all information from your comments into the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use countifs date from the END column?](http://superuser.com/questions/1044294/how-to-use-countifs-date-from-the-end-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to: write a formula into cells C9:AU9 in BRICKWORK_SUMMARY worksheet. You want this formular to display a count of corresponding dates (from C6:AU6 in BRICKWORK_SUMMARY worksheet) as they appear in End Date columns of BF TO TYPICAL worksheet.

Enter this formular into C8 of BRICKWORK_SUMMARY:

```
=COUNTIFS('BF TO TYPICAL'!$H:$I,C$6)+COUNTIFS('BF TO TYPICAL'!$Q:$R,C$6)+COUNTIFS('BF TO TYPICAL'!$Z:$AA,C$6)
```

You will need to repeat the COUNTIFS() part for each set of columns (Corner Type B, Corner Type A, etc).

Comment: Thanks and correct, but is there any simple way? because it need to repeat each column. I afraid will be confuse if there is more then 8 column

Comment: I think you will need to repeat for each End Date column. However, you can copy & paste this formular across the row in the BRICKWORK_SUMMARY worksheet (eg D8 to AU8) - it will automatically filter on the correct date (referenced as `C$6` in the proposed solution).

Comment: If you have sets of rows for each floor (eg L1, 2F, 3F) going down in BF TO TYPICAL worksheet - we CAN optimise the formular to perform the `COUNT` in the correct part of each End Date column in BF TO TYPICAL (instead of in the whole column). If this is the case, Edit your question to include info about the first and last row numbers for each floor's End Date sections (eg for L1, first End Date is at **H39**; where is the last End Date?; what are first and last End Date rows for L2, etc?).